# PDO Inserts data twice on single query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a terrible problem with pdo statements.
My class generate a SQL Query based on the Object, then forward the query and params to Bd Class and execute, but data is inserted twice to database.

Table in database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `es_simple_object` (
    `id_object` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id_object`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Generated query

```
INSERT INTO es_simple_object (es_simple_object.id_object, es_simple_object.active) VALUES (NULL, ?)
```

Generated params array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

call Db function

```
static::$db = Db::getInstance();    
static::$db->_execute($sql, $params);
```

Bd Class (just functions used to this job)

```
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance))
            self::$instance = new Db();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
        $connection = 'mysql:host='.$this->server.'; port='.$this->port.'; dbname='._DB_NAME_.'; charset='._DB_CHARSET_;

        try 
        {
            $this->link = new PDO($connection, _DB_USER_, _DB_PASSWD_);
            $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } 
        catch (PDOException $ex) 
        {   
            Tools::_catchException($ex);

            exit;
        }

        return $this->link;
    }

    public function _execute($sql, $params = array())
    {
        try
        {           
            $pdoStatement = $this->link->prepare($sql);
            $pdoStatement->execute($params == null ? array(null) : $params);

            $this->rows_affected = $pdoStatement->rowCount();
            $this->rows_returned = $pdoStatement->columnCount();
            $this->last_id = $this->link->lastInsertId();
            $this->result = $pdoStatement;

            return $pdoStatement;
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) 
        {
            Tools::_catchException($ex, array($sql, $params));

            return false;
        }
    }
```

I have no more ideas how to solve this problem

Comment: Could you also show your `Db::getInstance()` method?

Comment: Is it possible that your are calling the `_execute` function twice like in a loop or something. You can use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) in your `_execute` function to see everytime it is called and from where.

Comment: @dan08 I checked this, but everything looks fine, function is called one time. I tried run this functions on localhost, the same result.

Comment: I wrote a query by hand and call `_execute` function from index.php, but result is still the same

Comment: @PawełSkuza Why are you trying to extend PDO? Why `return $pdoStatement;` ?

Comment: @davidstrachan I'm using this for other functions, this has no impact on the above issue. I suspect that the problem lies with the database server and function AUTO_INCREMENT. My provider using 5.0.x version of mysql server. On version 5.5.x this problem disappears. But most of providers have older versions on their servers.

Comment: A long time ago I had a similar problem, but I don't used PDO, but the (now) deprecated `mysql_` functions. It turned out that for some wired reason, which had something to do with the apache, the whole script was sometimes executed more than one time. Sadly it is to long ago that I cannot remember the details, but maybe you want to check if the problem is not directly *in* your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @James Taylor for the suggestion of `.htaccess` file. The problem was hiding in RewriteRule and parameter `QSA`.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you attempting to insert a `NULL` to the `id_object` column, when `NULL` is not allowed per the column constraints?

Instead, shouldn't you perhaps leave `id_object` out of the `INSERT` statement, and let MySQL add a new autoincremented value there?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some logging on the page that calls _execute() and include a timestamp. See if for some reason the page is being requested more than once.

If that is the case you should be able to track down whether it is due to something in .htaccess etc.

If that does nothing for you, try commenting out

```
$this->result = $pdoStatement;

        return $pdoStatement;
```

This way you can test to see if it has something to do with your calling $pdoStatement again.